# js delete object reference from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

When the same object reference exists in two arrays, the objects are equivalent, and updating one affects the other.

However deleting the object from one array does not delete it in the other.

Why not?

```
var a1 = [
  {i: 0, s: 'zero'}, 
  {i: 1, s: 'one'}
];

var a2 = [
  a1[0],
  a1[1]
];

// items point to same reference
print(a1[0] === a2[0]); // true (equivalent)

// updating one affects both
a1[0].s += ' updated';
print(a1[0] === a2[0]); // true (still equivalent)
print(a1[0]); // {"i":0,"s":"zero updated"}
print(a2[0]); // {"i":0,"s":"zero updated"}

// however, deleting one does not affect the other
delete a1[0];
print(a1[0]); // undefined
print(a2[0]); // {"i": 0, "s": "zero"}
```

Interestingly, deleting a property from one, does affect the other.

```
delete a1[1].s;
print(a1[1]); // {"i":1}
print(a2[1]); // {"i":1}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kevincollins/4j6hj2v7/3/

Comment: You delete a reference to the value, not the value itself. See it like assigning a name to a person. If you stop calling them Chris they don't suddenly disappear.

Comment: Objects are assigned using reference. So when you do `a1[0]`, it will fetch its reference and copy it in array and will use it to access value. So when you delete reference, you remove the original location and hence it will reflect in all variables

Comment: Don't use `delete` on arrays. Just set the index to `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi Since arrays are objects, how is using `delete` harmful? I get that you're creating a holed array, but that isn't a problem to standard APIs

Comment: @MayorMonty Yes, thats true, but you are replacing the value stored in array and not changing the ref itself

Comment: @MayorMonty Holed arrays *are* a problem, for understanding, performance, and correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer why last `print(a2[0]);` still shows value, lets start analyzing the code.

Your `a1` is an array and when you initialize it with objects, it will create objects and store their reference.

```js
var a1 = [
  {i: 0, s: 'zero'}, // ref 1001
  {i: 1, s: 'one'}   // ref 1002
];
```

This part, by your comments is clear, but what happens when you do `delete a1[0]`?

Will it remove the object? Answer is No. It will remove the property stored at `0`th index in `a1` and set it to `undefined`. But if you delete the property of the object held at that reference, it will show in both: [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/4j6hj2v7/7/)

What happens to the object then? The value is retained and will be garbage collected if no one is referring it. In your case, since `a2[0]` still is accessing it, it will retain the value.

You can check following [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/4j6hj2v7/5/) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Halcyon said, you are deleting the reference, not the object itself. To demonstrate, look at the following example:

```
var a = 2
var b = [a, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you were to `delete b[0]`, you would only delete the reference, and thus, `a===2`. However, if you were to delete the reference at `a`, via `delete a`, then the value in `b` would be changed to `undefined`, because the reference that used to exist at that location no longer does

Comment: That's kinda what I was expecting. However in this example, `a` doesn't get deleted. https://jsfiddle.net/kevincollins/f30euchx/

Comment: @KevinCollins It's important to remember that literals (numbers, strings, etc.) cannot be deleted and if you reference one, you cannot `delete` it